# Does the matrix $U$ that diagonalize another matrix $M$ also diagonalize the derivative of $M$?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

I have a $3\times3$ Hermitian matrix $M$. All the elements of $M$ are a function of variable $x$. There is a unitary matrix $U$ that diagonalize $M$, i.e.
$$
D=U^\dagger MU
$$
I wonder if the same $U$ matrix always diagonalize $\frac{dM}{dx}$?

Comment: Are $U$ functions of $x$?

Comment: @ArcticChar yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the special case where $D$ is a constant real diagonal matrix, $U=e^{tK}$ for some constant real skew-symmetric matrix $K$ and $t$ is a real parameter. We have
\begin{aligned}
U^\dagger \dot{M} U
&=U^\dagger \dot{M} U\\
&=U^\dagger (\dot{U}DU^\dagger + U\dot{D}U^\dagger + UD\dot{U}^\dagger) U\\
&=U^\dagger (UKDU^\dagger + 0 - UDKU^\dagger) U\\
&=KD-DK,
\end{aligned}
which is not a diagonal matrix when $K\ne0$ and $D$ has distinct nonzero diagonal elements.